# После выполнения метода переменная обнуляется

Tags: java, android

в коде ниже осуществляется проверка того, что переменная count_m_shop равняется 0 после выполнения

сокращенный Java код:

```
 public class Menu_of_levels extends AppCompatActivity {

    public int count_m_hair_cut;
    public int count_m_shop;
    public int count_m_gun_shop;
    public int count_m_clothes_shop;
    TextView text;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu_of_levels);
        text=findViewById(R.id.textView);

 ImageButton button_shop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_shop);
        button_shop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                count_m_gun_shop=0;
                count_m_clothes_shop=0;
                count_m_shop=1;
                if(count_m_shop==1){
                    text.setText("в методе переменная равна 1");
                
            }
               }
        });
        if (count_m_shop==1){
             text.setText(text.getText()+"  переменная все еще равна 1");
        }
    }
}
```

в итоге при нажатии (и до него) в эмуляторе на соответствующую кнопку выводилось лишь "в методе переменная равна 1"

Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: android-studio метка используется для вопросов связанных непосредственно с IDE и как с ней работать, просьба это учитывать в будущем

Comment: у вас условный оператор стоит сразу после изменения переменной, а это наверное не так как вы планировали по итогу срабатывает, уточните пожалуйста как именно у вас должно оно все работать

Comment: я использовал оператор чтобы показать, что значение переменной изменилось,  опустил те действия которые мне нужны, для упрощения понимания

Comment: так у вас в каждом нажатии будет срабатывать условный оператор, переместите блок проверки выше изменения самой переменной, и второй условный оператор никогда не выполнится, разве что при входе на активность у вас будет переменная уже равна 1

Comment: сделайте вообще в обработке нажатий там где if добавьте else где будете менять переменные которые нужно, и все, тогда точно не ошибетесь

Comment: мне нужно чтобы переменная после того ей присвоено значение 1(в методе Onclick) сохранила его и при наследовании у меня был доступ к этой переменной в другом классе через экземпляр

Comment: что? при каком наследовании, через какой экземпляр? максимум что вы можете сделать это сохранить в отдельный класс как поле и потом оттуда вытаскивать :)

Answer (score 0):

По итогу обработку нажатий как я и говорил лучше сделать так:

```
button_shop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        count_m_gun_shop=0;
        count_m_clothes_shop=0;
        if(count_m_shop==1){
            text.setText("в методе переменная равна 1");
        }else{
            count_m_shop=1;
        }
    }
});
```

и вот этот кусок кода:

```
if (count_m_shop==1){
   text.setText(text.getText()+"  переменная все еще равна 1");
}
```

не выполнится никогда при условии что вы не выложили сюда код без присваивания через intent переменной значение 1. В противном случае его можно убрать/изменить. Также можно вместо цифрового отображения нажатий использовать булевскую переменную типа:

```
boolean isPressed = false;
button_shop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
    
            count_m_gun_shop=0;
            count_m_clothes_shop=0;
            if(isPressed){
                text.setText("в методе переменная равна 1");
            }else{
                isPressed = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Переменная не обнуляется - она изначально равна нулю и на момент проверки всё ещё равна нулю. Почему? - потому что проверка выполняется в методе `onCreate()`, который выполняется при запуске активности и в этот момент ваша кнопка ещё даже не появилась на экране. По кнопке вы кликнете когда-нибудь потом и только тогда переменная изменится, потому что она изменяется не в `onCreate()`, а в `onClick()`. Если не понятно о чём я - добавьте после условия:

```
        if (count_m_shop==1){
             text.setText(text.getText()+"  переменная все еще равна 1");
        }
        text.setText(text.getText() + "  переменная равна " + count_m_shop + ", а onCreate уже кончился");
```

Правило таково: всё что вы хотели сделать после нажатия на кнопку - следует делать в её обработчике `onClick()` (так же не возбраняется описать логику в отдельном методе и вызвать его из обработчика).

Answer (score 0):

У вас и при нажатии выводилась что переменная равна 1 потому что вы переменную `count_m_shop=1;` прописали в обработчик нажатий а не до него, а до этого у переменной `count_m_shop` было значение null а не 0. Предполагаю вам нужно так:

```
public class Menu_of_levels extends AppCompatActivity {

    public int count_m_hair_cut;
    public int count_m_shop;
    public int count_m_gun_shop;
    public int count_m_clothes_shop;
    TextView text;
    ImageButton button_shop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu_of_levels);
        text=findViewById(R.id.textView);

        button_shop = findViewById(R.id.button_shop);
        button_shop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                count_m_gun_shop = 1;
                count_m_clothes_shop = 1;
                if(count_m_shop != 0){
                    text.setText("в методе переменная равна 1");

                }
            }
        });
        
        getNumber();
    }

    private void getNumber() {
        count_m_hair_cut = 0;
        count_m_shop = 0;
        count_m_gun_shop = 0;
        count_m_clothes_shop = 0;
    }
}
```